# XML to XSL format

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

My response for the jquery call will be in XML format as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<transactions>
    <transaction>
        <date>12/23/2013</date>// First element
    <transaction>
    <transaction>
        <date>12/24/2013</date> // Second element
    <transaction>
</transactions>
```

This will be the response formatted from java.

In success function for jquery

```js
success: function(xmlData){
    alert(xmlData) //I'm getting alert as above format
    var xsl = // load my xsl format
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        // For IE I'm using IE 8
        xmlData.transformNode(xsl); // I'm getting  'object doesn't support this property or method'
    }
}
```

please help me to resolve the above mentioned problem.

Comment: Did you set `dataType: "xml"` property for jquery ajax?

Comment: Are those java style comments in your xml??? If you just want to mark elements for us, use xml comments, i.e. `<!-- comment -->`

Comment: Oops, that I missed out Thank you @SyamS